# Swiper's "imagesReady" event not firing

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/) mobile touch slider (v. 4.0.5). I'm having a problem that I think is related to the slider initializing before images are loaded, which causes it not to function.

The only solution I've found is to call `update()` after a delay.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  mySwiper.update();
}, 500);
```

But I don't like the half-second delay. If the slider must be reinitialized after images are loaded, I would rather that it happen efficiently as soon as the images are ready.

Documentation lists a `updateOnImagesReady` parameter which, when set to true, should reinitialize the slider after all of its images are loaded. But it doesn't seem to help.

> `updateOnImagesReady`
>   When enabled Swiper will be reinitialized after all inner images ( tags) are loaded.
>   Required `preloadImages: true`

Under ["events"](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#events), the documentation lists an `imagesReady` event. I thought I could use this event to call `update()`.

> `imagesReady`
>   Event will be fired right after all inner images are loaded.
>   `updateOnImagesReady` should be also enabled

In my code below, the `init` event seems to fire, but I can't get `imagesReady` to fire.
**Why is the `imagesReady` event not firing?**

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {

  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  grabCursor: true,
  effect: 'fade',
  preloadImages: true,
  updateOnImagesReady: true,

  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  on: {
    init: function() {
      console.log('initialized.'); // this works
    },
    imagesReady: function() {
      console.log('images ready.'); // this doesn't work
    }
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.5/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.5/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">

  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img srcset="//dummyimage.com/360x200/F00/fff&text=360w 360w,
                     //dummyimage.com/450x200/F00/fff&text=450w 450w,
                     //dummyimage.com/600x200/F00/fff&text=600w 600w,
                     //dummyimage.com/900x200/F00/fff&text=900w 900w" 
             sizes="100vw"
             src="//dummyimage.com/360x200/F00/fff&amp;text=default"
             alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img srcset="//dummyimage.com/360x200/0F0/fff&text=360w 360w,
                     //dummyimage.com/450x200/0F0/fff&text=450w 450w,
                     //dummyimage.com/600x200/0F0/fff&text=600w 600w,
                     //dummyimage.com/900x200/0F0/fff&text=900w 900w" 
             sizes="100vw"
             src="//dummyimage.com/360x200/0F0/fff&amp;text=default"
             alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img srcset="//dummyimage.com/360x200/00F/fff&text=360w 360w,
                     //dummyimage.com/450x200/00F/fff&text=450w 450w,
                     //dummyimage.com/600x200/00F/fff&text=600w 600w,
                     //dummyimage.com/900x200/00F/fff&text=900w 900w" 
             sizes="100vw"
             src="//dummyimage.com/360x200/00F/fff&amp;text=default"
             alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

</div>
```

---

Possibly related:
[Swiper slider not working unless page is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770106/swiper-slider-not-working-unless-page-is-resized)
[Swiper slider space between not showing on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668234/swiper-slider-space-between-not-showing-on-load)
[iDangero Swiper only work when screen is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785392/idangero-swiper-only-work-when-screen-is-resized)
[swiper doesn't work on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260363/swiper-doesnt-work-on-page-load)

---

Edit:

The initialization problem seems to go away if I remove the `effect:'fade'` parameter. See [slideChangeStart event does not fire when I swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535613/slidechangestart-event-does-not-fire-when-i-swipe). But I want to use the "fade" effect. And I'd still like to know how to get the events to fire.

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to be fixed in [version 4.0.7](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/commit/bc4149b70fe8b605db45eb9494efedc73173dd69#diff-a6983127d32be02db958853a990c1924).
I'm not exactly sure why, but it might be due to [changes on line 5958](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/commit/bc4149b70fe8b605db45eb9494efedc73173dd69#diff-d2283fc772b2ce59dfe110e7f4fe755eL5958).

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {

  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  grabCursor: true,
  effect: 'fade',
  preloadImages: true,
  updateOnImagesReady: true,

  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  on: {
    init: function() {
      console.log('initialized.'); // this works
    },
    imagesReady: function() {
      console.log('images ready.'); // this works now, too!
    }
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">

  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img srcset="//dummyimage.com/360x200/F00/fff&text=360w 360w,
                     //dummyimage.com/450x200/F00/fff&text=450w 450w,
                     //dummyimage.com/600x200/F00/fff&text=600w 600w,
                     //dummyimage.com/900x200/F00/fff&text=900w 900w" 
             sizes="100vw"
             src="//dummyimage.com/360x200/F00/fff&amp;text=default"
             alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img srcset="//dummyimage.com/360x200/0F0/fff&text=360w 360w,
                     //dummyimage.com/450x200/0F0/fff&text=450w 450w,
                     //dummyimage.com/600x200/0F0/fff&text=600w 600w,
                     //dummyimage.com/900x200/0F0/fff&text=900w 900w" 
             sizes="100vw"
             src="//dummyimage.com/360x200/0F0/fff&amp;text=default"
             alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img srcset="//dummyimage.com/360x200/00F/fff&text=360w 360w,
                     //dummyimage.com/450x200/00F/fff&text=450w 450w,
                     //dummyimage.com/600x200/00F/fff&text=600w 600w,
                     //dummyimage.com/900x200/00F/fff&text=900w 900w" 
             sizes="100vw"
             src="//dummyimage.com/360x200/00F/fff&amp;text=default"
             alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having an issue where the `imagesReady` event wasn't firing for me, but it seems like it was because I was loading all the images as background images instead of inline image tags.